# Hibernate - How to persist a new item in a Collection without loading the entire Collection

Tags: hibernate, refactoring

I have a collection in my model that contains a set of 'previous versions' of my root domain object. The previous versions are therefore 'immutable' and we will never want to update them, and only want to add past versions as they arise. Also the 'versioned' domain object is fairly complex and causes heavy database access to retrieve.

When I have a new version of one of these objects I want to save it with the others without loading the entire set. The Advanced FAQ has some advice on this:

> Why does Hibernate always initialize a collection when I only want to add or remove an element?
>
> Unfortunately the collections API defines method return values that may only be computed by hitting the database. There are three exceptions to this: Hibernate can add to a `<bag>`, `<idbag>` or `<list>` declared with `inverse="true"` without initializing the collection; the return value must always be true.
>
> If you want to avoid extra database traffic (ie. in performance critical code), refactor your model to use only many-to-one associations. This is almost always possible. Then use queries in place of collection access.

I am new to all of this and am not 100% sure on how to refactor your model to use only many-to-one associations. Can anyone please give me an example of point me to a tutorial so that I can learn how this will resolves my issue?

Comment: I think what I really need is 1) to be able to use a 'hibernate filter' to retrieve only the head revision on loading the collection (except for audit reports); and then 2) if this head is modified by an operation (causing two elements in the collection) tell hibernate just to update the current 'head' (as not being the head anymore) and then inserting the new version into the database.

Unfortunately, if we take this approach Hibernate seems to think the elements that were filtered (past revisions) are no longer associated with the parent set. setting immutable='true' seems not to work.

Comment: Glad we could help. If you liked some answers, you could vote for them (press the little arrow to the top), to thank people for their time. Also, if an answer is good enough for you, if you go to something else, you could mark one answer as being the 'accepted' one.

Answer (score 11):

When you have a List or Set-based collection and you add a new object into your collection, Hibernate will always hit the database because it compare one by one object by using equals implementation before saving or updating - when using a Set - or by comparing a index column when using a List. This behavior is needed because of the Set and List semantic. Because of that, the performance of your application can decrease significantly whether you have a bunch of records.

Some workaround to overcome this issue

**1º** Conversion pattern by using a encapsuled Bag collection plus your desired Set or List exposed as a property

```
@Entity
public class One {

    private Collection<Many> manyCollection = new ArrayList<Many>();

    @Transient
    public Set<Many> getManyCollectionAsSet() { return new HashSet<Many>(manyCollection); }
    public void setManyCollectionAsSet(Set<Many> manySet) { manyCollection = new ArrayList<Many>(manySet); }

    /**
      * Keep in mind that, unlike Hibernate, JPA specification does not allow private visibility. You should use public or protected instead
      */
    @OneToMany(cascade=ALL)
    private Collection<Many> getManyCollection() { return manyCollection; }
    private void setManyCollection(Collection<Many> manyCollection) { this.manyCollection = manyCollection; }

}
```

**2º** Use ManyToOne instead of OneToMany

```
@Entity
public class One {

    /**
      * Neither cascade nor reference
      */

}

@Entity
public class Many {

    private One one;

    @ManyToOne(cascade=ALL)
    public One getOne() { return one; }
    public void setOne(One one) { this.one = one }

}
```

**3º** Caching - when applied because of, depending on your requirements, your configuration can increase or decrease the performance of your application. See [here](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#performance-cache-readonly)

**4°** SQL constraint - If you want a collection that behaves like a Set, you can use a SQL constraint, which can be applied to a column or *set of columns*. See [here](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_unique.asp)

Comment: I think it does read the current collection in order to do the add. This is because it needs to check the `Set` constraints. i.e. it needs to see if the entity that you're adding is already in the collection, as it has to return false if it is already there.

Answer (score 8):

The way I typically do this is to define the collection as "inverse".

That roughly means: the primary definition of the 1-N association is done at the "N" end. If you want to add something to the collection you alter the associated object of the detail data.

A small XML example:

```
<class name="common.hibernate.Person" table="person">
    <id name="id" type="long" column="PERSON_ID">
        <generator class="assigned"/>
    </id>
    <property name="name"/>
    <bag name="addresses" inverse="true">
        <key column="PERSON_ID"/>
        <one-to-many class="common.hibernate.Address"/>
    </bag>
 </class>

 <class name="common.hibernate.Address" table="ADDRESS">
    <id name="id" column="ADDRESS_ID"/>
    <property name="street"/>
    <many-to-one name="person" column="PERSON_ID"/>
   </class>
```

then the update is done exclusively in Address:

```
Address a = ...;
a.setPerson(me);
a.setStreet("abc");
Session s = ...;
s.save(a);
```

Done. You did not even touch the collection. Consider it read-only, which may be very practical for querying with HQL, and iterating and displaying it.

Comment: Many thanks for your time and advice.

This is an excellent suggestion. I looked into this, but, unfortunately I had two conflicting issues: 1) The 'managed-sub-components' are from an external system so I cannot add the necessary inverse association to them; 2) furthermore the owning entity already declares the 'type' of the 'managed-sub-component' in a superclass making it difficult to create and intermediate wrapper.

However, this advice would be suitable for others in a similar situation I feel.

Thanks!

Comment: a.setPerson(me) => now I understand! Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

I used to create a native query for this cases, like below:

```
    @Modifying
    @Transactional
    @Query(nativeQuery = true, value = "INSERT INTO categorytopic_topic(category_id, topic_id) VALUES (?1, ?2)")
    public void addTopic(long categoryId, long topicId);
```

It's very fast because does not need load the collection.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand well your need:

- you have an **in-memory add-only collection of immutable objects**
- how to add an item to that collection without initializing the entire collection (in the current Session)?

Did you consider **maintaining your collection disconnected**?

- Load it once when the application starts
- Adding an element would mean two operations, done by a single service in only one place:

  - save the element (fast database operation, no cascading is done to the parent)
  - add the element to the existing disconnected collection (no database operation)

Comment: Many thanks for your time and advice. 

There is a top-level entity that maintains a single collection (a Map) of the previous and the current versions of the managed sub-component.

The user can specify arbitrary operations on the current managed sub-component. If any of these operations result in a modification to the sub-component then the current version should become the previous version and the new altered version the 'head'.


I will look into the removal of the cascading operation and handling it manually then. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This will minimize selected data

@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)

But be carefull with N+1 problems in foreach iterating this collection.