# Add child object to parent without querying parent

Tags: nhibernate

How can I add a child object to a parent collection while keeping the integrity of my domain model without issuing a `select` statement to fetch the parent?

I have the following model:

```
public class Post
{
    private readonly IList<Comment> _comments = new List<Comment>();
    public virtual IList<Comment> Comments { get { return _comments; } }

    public virtual void AddComment(string text)
    {
        var comment = new Comment
            {
                Post = this,
                Text = text
            };

        _comments.Add(comment);
    }
}

public class Comment
{
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual Post Post { get; set; }
    public virtual string Text { get; set; }
}
```

Here is what I'm currently doing:

```
var post = session.Load<Post>(1);
post.AddComment("Test comment.");
transaction.Commit();
```

The issue with this approach is that when I call `AddComment()` on the `Post` proxy NHibernate  loads the entire post, thus issuing a select statement against the database. I would like to protect the the `_comments` list by always having to call `AddComment()` to add comments.

Is it possible to keep the integrity of my domain models and adding children to parents without querying the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways I can think of:

1. Don't map the Comments list, only map the Post of each comment. When you need the entire comments list, load it dynamically by finding all Comments with a certain Parent [Add to Nhibernate collection without initializing the collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6985798/add-to-nhibernate-collection-without-initializing-the-collection). This will keep your domain model integrity.
2. Map both ways but make the update comment's parent, not the list. The lists will get updated the next time you'll load them from the db. This is more problematic because your domain is not correct during the process, but may still be OK - it depends on your requirements, and whether your domain is accessed during the process (I assume you do not need the lists, since you do not wish to load them)
3. Bypass NHibernate entirely. I once had to do something like this. I had a scenario where a parent object had a huge set of strings and I needed to add even more strings to each set. There's no parent field on a string and I did not wish to wrap them in an object. I don't 
   remember if I had other reasons, but I did have a very pressing deadline and a severe performance issue. I created a simple SQL query to do the job and it did it well. Not a solution I'm proud of, but this was one of the instances in which I felt an ORM is not exactly the tool for the job. I was worried about future changes to the column or table names, but since my mapping was done in code using Fluent Nhibernate the matter was resolved.

Answer (score 1):

If you set `inverse=true` on the IList mapping in `Post`, then the `Comment` entity will be responsible for maintaining the relationship.  Something like this should work:

```
var comment = new Comment();
comment.Post = session.Load<Post>(1);
comment.Text = "Test comment";
transaction.Commit();
```

As an alternative, though, consider whether a select by primary key is really going to cause that big of a performance hit; in most cases, it won't.  NHibernate will, at times, issue an extra SELECT that you wouldn't see in a hand-rolled data access layer.  You can try to circumvent this, like you're doing here, but it may not be worth it.  Consider it a (very small) price to pay for the convenience of an ORM.  Deal with performance problems when they come up, and not before.