# Hibernate OneToMany bi-directional relation is slow

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, bidirectional

I have `Sessions` and `Users` classes with following `bi-directional` `OneToMany`mapping(generated with hibernate reverse engineering tool):

```
public class Users {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="users")
    public Set<Sessions> getSessionses() {
        return this.sessionses;
    }
}

public class Sessions {
    @ManyToOne(fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="USER_ID")
    public Users getUsers() {
        return this.users;
    }
}
```

And here is my code which creates new session for user:

```
Session s = ...;
Users user = (Users) s.createCriteria(Users.class)
             ./*restrictions...*/.uniqueResult();
Sessions userSession = new Sessions();
userSession.setUsers(user);
s.save(userSession);
user.getSessionses().add(userSession); // here getSessionses() has 2k records
```

User has 2k sessions and therefore last line is very slow.

**How can I link session with user without fetching whole sessions collection ?**

Comment: How do you load the `user` entity?

Comment: Do you really need the collection to be a Set? When you add an element into it,  hibernate needs to load the elements to check for duplicates

Comment: @Guillaume Set is rather the mandate data-structure imposed by Hibernate to maintain the uniqueness

Comment: When you have unique ids your results are results are unique anyway. But with a list you could speed the process up.

Comment: This might be a duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409523/hibernate-how-to-persist-a-new-item-in-a-collection-without-loading-the-entire

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have a look at Hibernate's [extra-lazy loading](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/annotations/api/org/hibernate/annotations/LazyCollectionOption.html) feature.
You enable that by annotating your collection with `@LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)`. There is [this example](https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/java/hibernate-extra-lazy-collection-fetching) to look at, and there's `Set` used in [this one](http://learningviacode.blogspot.hu/2012/07/lazyextra.html).

```
public class Users {
    @OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="users")
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.EXTRA)
    public Set<Sessions> getSessionses() {
        return this.sessionses;
    }
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks! It works perfectly. In this case hibernate generates only single query: `SELECT 1 FROM SESSIONS WHERE USER_ID=? and SESSION_ID=?`. It's the only solution, which helps to fix issue without having to change Set<Sessions> to List<Sessions>.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not certain if hibernate would add this connection both ways but instead of adding a `Session` to a `User` set the `User` of a `Session`. This way you don't have to load every session.

Comment: Hibernate [doc](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/tutorial.html#tutorial-associations-usingbidir) says, that: `"setting the link on both sides" is absolutely necessary with bi-directional links`. Therefore it's required to set link on both sides.

Comment: Can you refute my comment with any official documentation proof link ?