# Hibernate Insert Options

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

I am trying to efficiently implement a Hibernate connection in Java and recently came across two ways of adding database rows using Hibernate which I would like to discuss:

Given are the following SQL Tables:

```
CREATE TABLE Customer (
  customer_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  customer_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL UNIQUE KEY,
  PRIMARY KEY (customer_id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB;


CREATE TABLE Orders (
  order_id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  customer_name VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  order_date DATETIME,
  PRIMARY KEY(order_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (customer_name) REFERENCES Customer(customer_name)
  ON UPDATE CASCADE
  ON DELETE CASCADE
) ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

Customer is parent table and Orders is child table, 1:n relationship.

When I want to insert new Orders for a certain customer, which is already in the database I know to options how to achieve it :

```
(1)
// Saving the child table
// Query the customer
    Customer cu = (Customer) session.get(Customer.class, 1);
    Orders od = new Orders(cu, new Date());
    session.save(od);
// This seems to work fast and efficient

(2) Saving the parent table
// Due to bidirectional relationship one can also do:
Orders od = new Orders(cu, d);
cu.getOrderses().add(od);
session.save(cu);
// This is what is often shown in Hibernate tutorials, but seems to be really 
//   inefficient because the entire HashSet of the parent table needs to loaded //first,       
//before the new object can be added.
```

Benchmark example : (1)  0 sec  (2) 5 sec

Why is way (2) often shown in Tutorials even though it seems to be inefficient ?

Comment: Yes, way two is absolutely terrible. It's probably in the tutorials because it's more "object-oriented", completely disregarding the concern of SQL traffic.

Comment: However, even your way one fetches too much. All you need is the Customer ID and a property on the Orders entity which exposes the raw FK.

Comment: Option 2 seems to stem from not understanding the technology; I would expect controlled cascading to be in place so you don't need to manually save anything anyway. It is not -necessarily- bad though, as per usual it always depends on the context. If the list of orders can be potentially very large (in which case the performance problem starts to apply), I wouldn't map it as a collection to begin with. But in any case: my compliments that you question this and think about it rather than just blindly adopting what you find. I'd hire you.

Answer (score 1):

Which option you should choose depents on your model. Do you have/need a collection of orders in the Customer? Then you have to add the object anyway and you should choose (2).

Take care of proper fetch configuration or otherwise Hibernate will load the whole collection even if you don't need it. For that case take a look at [Hibernate - How to persist a new item in a Collection without loading the entire Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409523/hibernate-how-to-persist-a-new-item-in-a-collection-without-loading-the-entire).

If you don't have a collection in Customer then use option (1).

(2) is often shown in tutorials to show the capabilities of Hibernate/ORMs in general. It's also more object oriented but I would recomment to create a method `Customer.addOrder()` or even `Customer.creatOrder()` instead od directly manipulating the collection from outside.

Comment: Thank you very much the link. It explains well that option inverse="true" makes it possible to use (1) in both situations.