# hibernate lazy fetch,how to add @ManytoMany associations?

Tags: spring, hibernate, collections, many-to-many, fetch

I have two entities: Movie and Cinema, and they have a @ManyToMany association. Cinema is the owning side, in both side, I keep a collection to store fks, and both side is lazy-fetched:

```
@Table(name="Cinema")
@Entity
public class Cinema {
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            fetch=FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinTable(name = "cinema_movie",
            joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "cinema_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)},
            inverseJoinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "movie_id", nullable = false, updatable = false)})
private @Getter @Setter Set<Movie> movies = new HashSet<Movie>();
...
}

@Entity
@Table(name="Movie")
public class Movie {
@ManyToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
            mappedBy = "movies")
private @Getter @Setter Set<Cinema> cinemas = new HashSet<Cinema>();
...
}
```

Because I'm using lazy-fetch, If I test the following code, I will get a 
"LazyInitializationException":

```
//mp and cp means MovieRepo and CinemaRepo
Cinema c2 = new Cinema();
        c2.setCity(1);
        c2.setAddress("chigang");
        c2.setName("feiyang");
    cp.save(c2);
    m = mp.findByName("Zootopia");
    //m = mp.fetchCinemas(m.getId());
    m.addCinema(c2);
    c2.addMovie(m);
    cp.save(c);
```

If I uncomment `//m = mp.fetchCinemas(m.getId());` the exception is gone. As you can predict, I execute the following sql query in this method:

```
@Query(
        "SELECT c FROM Cinema c INNER JOIN FETCH c.movies "+ 
        "WHERE c.id = :cid"
      )
Cinema fetchMovies(@Param("cid") Long cid);
```

But when I just want to associate a Movie with a Cinema, it's cumbersome to explicitly fetch All the Cinemas, and then add one to it, and then save them all.

***How can I add a Cinema to m's collection without fetching all Cinemas associated with m??***

Or maybe I have problem understanding lazy-fetched collections in hibernate. I'm new to hibernate and Spring. Any Help is appreciated. (If you read my question to this line, thank you whatever <3 )

Answer (score 0):

If you don`t want to fetch all the collection items before adding a new element, you have use **Bag** Collection instead of **Set**.

Please refer to the post below which explains all various ways of achieving it:

[Hibernate - How to persist a new item in a Collection without loading the entire Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409523/hibernate-how-to-persist-a-new-item-in-a-collection-without-loading-the-entire)