# How to add child record in a Unidirectional @OneToMany without retrieving previous records

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-data

I'm dealing with a unidirectional @OneToMany association that utilizes the "author_book" table as an intermediate table. However, when attempting to add a new Book to an Author in order to generate a new entry in the "author_book" table, I'm having to first retrieve all previous Books. This process becomes time-consuming, especially when an author has a substantial number of books. In my case, I cannot use a bidirectional @OneToMany association. Is there a more efficient way to accomplish this using a unidirectional approach?

Author Entity:

```
@Entity
public class AuthorEntity {
   @Id
   private long id;

   @OneToMany
   @JoinTable(name = "author_book", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_author"),
              inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "id_book"))
   private Set<BookEntity> books;
}
```

And Book Entity:

```
@Entity
public class BookEntity {
   @Id
   private long id;
}
```

Adding new Book

```
public void addBook(BookEntity book) {
    AuthorEntity author = authorRepository.findById(authorId);
    author.getBooks().add(book);
    entityManager.merge(author);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1. Change to **@ManyToOne** Relationship:**

One approach is to modify the relationship from @OneToMany to @ManyToOne. By doing this, you can establish a relationship from the book to its author. When adding a new book, you can simply set the author of the book, and Hibernate will efficiently execute a single insert statement. This method works well if you don't need to navigate from the author to their books directly.

```
BookEntity b = new BookEntity();
    AuthorEntity a = em.getReference(AuthorEntity.class, 1L);
    b.setAuthor(a);
    b.setId(342L);
    em.persist(b);
```

**2. **Native SQL Queries**:**

Another option is to create a native SQL query to perform the insertion directly. It will not load the entire collection because you will just insert the entity manually without loading it first.

Similar question: [Hibernate - How to persist a new item in a Collection without loading the entire Collection](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1409523/hibernate-how-to-persist-a-new-item-in-a-collection-without-loading-the-entire)

Comment: In my project, it wouldn't be possible to use @ManyToOne, but I followed the second solution and it worked out. Thanks